# CSS Transition Mouse Enter Animation and Mouse Out Animation

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to figure out css transition. I have an image that when a user hovers over it the title flys in from the left, but when they hover out i want the title to exit on the right side. Is this possible?

Here's my code:

```
ul.case-studies-list li div.content{
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
    opacity:0;
}

ul.case-studies-list li:hover div.content{
     transform-origin: bottom left;
     transform: translateX(0px);
     opacity: 1;
 }
```

Comment: You would need to have the image fly out, and then be immediately placed on the left side in 1 frame.

Comment: The image is in the html code (<img>) and not the css. The div masks the image on mouse over coming from the left. When they mouse out I want the mask to exit to the right. Sorry, I guess I'm not understanding what  you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple... I have made a [FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/Anuj_Kumar/2gba05ug/) for you.

```
 jsfiddle.net/Anuj_Kumar/2gba05ug/
```

Comment: Thank you! But i was trying to see if I could do it with just css and not javascript.